# Linux Box Internet Speed

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos-6

I have encountered a weird problem with my Centos6 Server, currently I have install Centos6.4 on a 64bit support CPU with 8GB of RAM and 500GB HDD. Just went to check on the internet this morning and I noticed a significant drop of the internet speed, when I double check on the speedtest I could barely have up to 3MB/s of speed while other local machines have 10MB/s... Yesterday it was just working fine... I have restarted the internet a couple of times but didn't get fixed the issue... Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Output of `ethtool eth0`

```
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Are these upload speeds? Download speeds? What does "restarted the internet" mean? Was it working for this machine before? Is this machine connected wirelessly or wired? You have to give us more details.

Comment: @David, Download speed up to 3MB/s(Before was 10MB/s) but on windows it gets 10MB/s. I restarted my Internet modem but didn't fix the problem. This machine is connected wired...

Comment: Could you post the output of ethtool eth0?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, I just updated the question with the result of the `ethtool eth0`...

Comment: Your output is fine, problem's elsewhere. You should try when there is no other significant traffic. Are you sure there was no one else downloading stuff at the same time? You should try at some other time, like late at night.